# Create a TF Dataset of SparseTensors with from_generator

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, sparse-matrix

I have a generator that yields `tf.sparse.SparseTensor`s.  I want to turn this into a Tensorflow Dataset, but am running into some issues.  I am using TF2.  First, unlike regular Tensors, you cannot simply pass them in (and providing the correct data types for output_types).  For a sparse tensor of `[1,0,0,0,5,0]`, the error looks like

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: TypeError: `generator` yielded an element that could not be converted to the expected type. The expected type was int64, but the yielded element was SparseTensor(indices=tf.Tensor(
E     [[0]
E      [4]], shape=(2, 1), dtype=int64), values=tf.Tensor([1 5], shape=(2,), dtype=int64), dense_shape=tf.Tensor([6], shape=(1,), dtype=int64)).
```

After doing some looking around on the internet, I found this open issue and tried to do something similar https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16689 - read the indices, values, and shape as separate tensors into a TF Dataset, and then mapping over the dataset to create the sparse tensor.  This is not working as shown in some of the examples in the github issue - `tf.sparse.SparseTensor(indices, values, shape)` does not seem to accept indices and shape in the form of a tf.Tensor - it will happily take in a list or numpy array, but not a Tensor.  Since `map` is not eager, I also cannot call `.numpy()` on the Tensor either.  What is best way to get this to work?  I see there is `tf.py_function`/`tf.numpy_function` which could help, but constructing the output type can be tricky (though not impossible) for my use case - the incoming data is not fixed and can have a mix of sparse and dense tensors.